# Why does Channel Images cache directory create itself as owner/group 99/99

Tags: channel-images

I have just installed a new EE site and the cache directory Channel Images creates is being set to Owner/Group 99/99. (/public_html/system/expressionengine/cache/channel_images)

When I try to upload a pic it gives me the error "**The Local Temp dir is either not writable or does not exist**".
When I try to import the image it will create the entry directory (/public_html/pictures/articles/1) but the image will not be created.

Also have Updater and Monitor from Devotee installed on same site and it works fine.
This is not happening on any another site I created on the same server just to test this out.

**Details:**
Server -- VPS running WHM/cPanel (CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 / WHM 11.42.0 (build 22), 77GB free disk space)
Cache dir permission -- 755 (this is normal for a cPanel server and works for all other sites)
EE -- 2.8.1
Channel Images -- 5.4.15
Field test output --
PHP Safe Mode (OFF): Passed
Is Dir: Passed
Is Readable: Passed
Is Writable: Passed
Create Test File: Passed
Delete Test File: Passed
Create Test DIR: Passed
Rename Test DIR: Passed
Delete Test DIR: Passed

I have tried all options in other topics (except manually changing owner/group using ssh as root) and nothing works. Re-installed Channel Images and it still creates the cache directory as Owner/Group 99/99.

Screenshots:
[image: cache directory permission]

[image: entry directory]

Note: This is also posted in DevDemon forum as topic https://www.devdemon.com/forums/viewthread/2692/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: **It was a bug in the Channel Images 5.4.15 build** in relation to cache directory creation and EE 2.8.
I got a new version of the build from DevDemon and all was fine.